# Сортировка несколько списков в одном столбце VBA excel

Tags: excel, сортировка, vba

Доброго времени суток,
Есть таблица, в первой колонке несколько списков с шапками.
Как отсортировать каждый список отдельно с помощью VBA?
Диапазоны списков постоянно меняются, поэтому задать конкретный диапазон не получиться, разве что переменными начало и конец каждого списка.
макросы только учу, не выходит у меня.
Заранее благодарю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как звучит вопрос?

Comment: Покажите пример расположения данных. По каким критериям можно определить начало и окончание списков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SortFruits()
Dim aFr(), aSort()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lRw As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long, m As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' отключаем обновление экрана'
    Set sht = ActiveSheet ' нужный лист в переменную'

    lRw = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' размер диапазона столбца А'
    aFr = sht.Range("A1:B" & lRw).Value ' данные в массив'

    For i = 1 To lRw ' по записям столбца А'
        If aFr(i, 2) = Empty Then ' к-ва нет (заголовок)'
            i = i + 1

            For k = i To lRw ' ищем конец списка'
                If aFr(k, 2) = Empty Then k = k - 1: Exit For ' к-ва нет (следующий заголовок)'
            Next k

            If k > lRw Then k = lRw ' для последнего списка'

            ' сортировка списка'
            With sht.Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=sht.Range("A" & i & ":A" & k), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange sht.Range("A" & i - 1 & ":B" & k)
                .Header = xlYes: .Apply
            End With
        End If

        i = k
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' включаем обновление экрана'
End Sub
```

Comment: Прекрасно, правда я не учел один момент, могут попадаться пустые ячейки в списке, можно что-то добавить? или лучше перед запустить макрос удаления пустых строк?

Comment: Пустые - без числа? Нужно удалять, ведь единственное, за что можно зацепиться при определении списка - отсутствие числа в начале и в конце. Если пустота внутри списка, код посчитает эту строку за его окончание. Вариант при наличии пустот: ввести в списки еще какой-либо критерий (нумерацию, выделение жирным шрифтом заголовка ...)

Comment: Хотя, если пустая вся строка, то можно обойти доп. проверкой на наличие текста в первом столбце. При этом, если не усложнять код, пустые строки останутся и тоже попадут в сортировку. Внутри цикла изменить строку: *If aFr(k, 2) = Empty And aFr(k, 1) <> Empty Then k = k - 1: Exit For*

Comment: Вариант с проверкой текста подошел. Благодарю

Comment: Прошу прощения за назойливость, как будет выглядеть код если заголовки будут выделены жирным

Comment: * If aFr(k, 1).Font.Bold = True Then...*

Comment: "run-time error '424' object required" ((

Comment: Да, ерунду написал. Не может значения из массива иметь формат ячейки. Нужно заглядывать в саму ячейку: * If sht.Cells(k, 1).Font.Bold = True Then...*

Comment: Супер!!! наилучший вариант! Благодарю

Comment: Можно еще вопрос? пытаюсь запустить на всех листах - (Dim a As Variant For a = 1 To 5) далее макрос сортировки где (Set sht = Worksheets(a)) и после (Next i Application.ScreenUpdating = True) (Next a
End Sub) к сожалению выполняет только на первом листе.(( А с помощью (For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ... Next sht) не пойму как задать лист в цикле сортировки.

Comment: Листы нужно задавать не в цикле сортировки, а гораздо раньше. Вопрос не связан с сортировкой.